# Server control collection property cannot add in designer

Tags: c#, asp.net, designer, custom-server-controls

I have a custom server control that has a collection property. I want to be able to add items in the collection property from the designer and see the result in the markup.
So far I am able to see the collection property in the designer and I add an item. However it doesn't generate the markup for the new item. 
Here is some part of my code:

```
[ParseChildren(true),
DefaultProperty("CompatibleBrowsers"),
Designer(typeof(BrowserCompatibilityControlDesigner)),
ToolboxData("<{0}:BrowserCompatibilityControl runat=server></{0}:BrowserCompatibilityControl>")]
public class BrowserCompatibilityControl : WebControl
{
    private List<CompatibleBrowser> _CompatibleBrowsers = new List<CompatibleBrowser>();

    public BrowserCompatibilityControl() : base() { }

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    Editor(typeof(BrowserCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)),
    NotifyParentProperty(true),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public List<CompatibleBrowser> CompatibleBrowsers { get { return _CompatibleBrowsers; } }

    ...
}
```

The Collection Items are of type `CompatibleBrowser`:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class CompatibleBrowser
{
    BrowserName _Name;
    int _MinVersion, _MaxVersion;

    public CompatibleBrowser() : this(BrowserName.Default, 0, 0) { }

    public CompatibleBrowser(BrowserName name, int minVersion, int maxVersion)
    {
        Name = name;
        MinVersion = minVersion;
        MaxVersion = maxVersion;
    }

    [
    Category("Behavior"),
    DefaultValue(""),
    Description("Name of browser"),
    NotifyParentProperty(true),
    ]
    public BrowserName Name { get { return _Name; } set { _Name = value; } }
    [
    Category("Behavior"),
    DefaultValue(""),
    Description("MinVersion"),
    NotifyParentProperty(true),
    ]
    public int MinVersion { get { return _MinVersion; } set { _MinVersion = value; } }
    [
    Category("Behavior"),
    DefaultValue(""),
    Description("MaxVersion"),
    NotifyParentProperty(true),
    ]
    public int MaxVersion { get { return _MaxVersion; } set { _MaxVersion = value; } }
}
```

And the markup looks like this:

```
<test:BrowserCompatibilityControl runat="server">
    <CompatibleBrowsers>
        <test:CompatibleBrowser Name="IE" MinVersion="9" />
        <test:CompatibleBrowser Name="Chrome" MinVersion="27" />
        <test:CompatibleBrowser Name="Mozilla" MinVersion="21" />
        <test:CompatibleBrowser Name="Opera" MinVersion="9" />
    </CompatibleBrowsers>
    ...
</test:BrowserCompatibilityControl>
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ok I understand. Sorry for that, it was not on purpose.